# Send select value to PHP via Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Have some problem sending select value to PHP via Ajax.

PHP:

```
<div class="kalb">
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['produktas'])) {

 $produktas = $_POST['produktas'];
 $infos = CalSkaiciuokle::where("id", $produktas);

 foreach ($infos as $info) {
      echo "<td><input type='text' name='ert' value=" $info->ert . " disabled></td>";
      echo "<td><input type='text' name='ert2' value=" . $info->ert2 . " disabled></td>";
      echo "<td><input type='text' name='ert3' value=" . $info->ert3. " disabled></td>";
      echo "<td><input type='text' name='ert4' value=" . $info->ert4. " disabled></td>";
 }
}  
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
   $('.subcategory').change(function(){
        var selected_item = $(this).val();
        console.log(selected_item);   

        $.ajax({
             type: 'post',
             url: 'ert.php',
             data: {
               produktas:selected_item
             },
             success: function (data) {
               // alert(data);
               document.getElementById("kalb").innerHTML=data;  
             }
        });
    });
```

When I select from select option and look to console it return value, but then I send via ajax it return a big HTML file and it destroys html structure.

Comment: This is the expected behavior. If you make a request of an HTML page you will get everything back from the page.

Comment: it's because you are printing something before sending headers in php.

Comment: so how can I pick only value i select and send to php? is it posible?

Comment: Yes - write discrete PHP for returning data. Have the PHP echo only what you want it to.

Comment: Where your select html tag? Do you have the .subcategory class into your select?